# Custom sorting of the collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have collection of objects. I need to sort it by difficult condition, using many properties and calculations. My solution is to define in object special `int` property, that returns value, that `OrderBy` shoultd sort by. This solution is not good enough.
For *example*, collection should be sorted first by `State` property, then if `State = 1`, by `Value1` property, if `State = 2`, by `Value2` property and so on.
Advice, please, some solution.

Comment: @Baszz, thanks for advice, but where is it possible to misunderstand? I provided small example of data, that I have to handle and there are 3 satisfactory answers already.

Comment: Okay, I removed it and upvoted again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order a collection by multiple criteria by using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) for the first criterium and chaining the other criteria after that using [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx).

Your first criterium is to simply order by the State property. Your second criterium depends on the State property; assuming that Value1, Value2 and so on have the same type, you can use a `switch` statement to select the right value:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> result = items
    .OrderBy(item => item.State)
    .ThenBy(item =>
    {
        switch (item.State)
        {
            case 1: return item.Value1;
            case 2: return item.Value2;
        }
        throw new Exception();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) and using OrderBy of LINQ

Answer (score 0):

you can use an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) class;
just put all the logic you've given above into its compare method.